# Please comment on data size of cipher block chaining (CBC) in symmetric encryption

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, cryptography

I am considering to use CBC to encrypt a block of data. Dose it make a sense to use CBC if the data to be encrypted is smaller than 2 blocks ? 
For example data block size for AES is 128 bits, and total data to be encrypted is less than 256 bits.

I appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  even if it is 1 block in size it makes sense.  This is because the IV is XOR'ed with the first block.  This means that even if you encrypt 2 identical plain text segments the resulting cipher text will be distinct.

Don't forget about [CWE-329](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/329.html).